# Showing data from the db on other parts of the page

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi guys I am relatively new to php and am wondering how there is a cleaner way to retrieve data from my database and show it across different parts of the webpage?

For example see my current code...

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   if($_SESSION['email'] == $row['email']) {
        // If you find the right user with the same E-Mail address, DO SOME COOL THINGS :)
   }
   echo '<h2>'. $row['username'] . '</h2>' ;
   echo 'Hi, I am a ' . $row['yourage'] . ' year old ' . $row['orientation'] . ' ' . $row['gender'] . ' looking for a ' . $row['lookingfor'] . '.<br /><br />';
   echo 'I am currently living in the ' . $row['location'] . ' area.';
   echo '<button>Get in touch</button>' . '<br>';
   echo '<br /><br />';
   echo '<hr />';
   echo '<h2>About me:</h2>';                   
   echo $row['aboutme'] . '<br>';
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

If I copy this again on the page it kills the script but wondering what the best practice is?

Comment: Have you tried assigning your results to variables, rather than just painting them out?  If you do that, you can reuse them whenever you want without having to run the entire script again.

Comment: @durbnpoisn that would make perfect sense to do that - could you show an example from my submitted code?

Comment: I was about to, but someone else just beat me to the punch.  There you go...

Comment: I forgot to add in my answer that the if statement you have inside you while loop is pointless, as you have already ascertained that the users email matches the inputted email in the MySQL query. But good effort with starting PHP and I hope you stick with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a much better approach to this would be to separate your database and view code, for example by using an MVC framework (such as CakePHP).

But here is what I would do if was doing this a similar way to you: (You are only selecting one result from the database, if you were selecting many, this would be different.)
At top of page:

```
<?php
$email = $_SESSION['email']; 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='".$email."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $member = $row;
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

then whenever you need to display the data in the page: (for example)

```
My username is <?php echo $member['username']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should separate the query script (below) from the viewing part.

query.php

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   if($_SESSION['email'] == $row['email']) {
        // If you find the right user with the same E-Mail address, DO SOME COOL THINGS :)
   }
   $returnArray[] = $row['username'];
   $returnArray[] = $row['yourage'];
   //and so on;
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Some view.php (or index.html renamed to index.php):

```
<?php
include('query.php');

var_dump($returnArray);
//Or with a foreach or however
```

But you should learn about [MVC Model View Controller](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) and as others said, use OO programming

Comment: if I used the above the message im getting back is NULL

Comment: Does the path of the include match the location of your query file or whatever you named it? I didn't test your code, I just wanted to give you a direction to go. I copied your code and I don't think the errror is in the var_dump part

Answer (score 0):

Learn [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)- this will help you separate this code from your application. Just make the ajax call to this php and get the result and show them how you want to show.

For example-

In a your application, say **app.html**, at the point you want to fetch something from db-

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "fetch.php", // your aove php file
  function(response){
     console.log(response); // you'll get all the rows here
     response=JSON.parse(response);
     for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
        console.log(response[i].username);  // show results in view
        ....
     }
  }
});
```

**fetch.php**

```
$myrows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   array_push($myrows, $row);
}
echo json_encode($myrows);
```

Comment: Oh really? Is that the best way to be dealing with information from a database?

Comment: A better suggestion would have been to learn object oriented php

Comment: @George Thank you for the suggestion I will go get my head into some good tutorials - I am just curious because I have created that from a couple of days messing around with php and just wanted to see how to show data on various parts of the webpage

Comment: @Sahil I have just used your code and it is full of errors?

Comment: Well this was just a suggestion, may be other answers could help you better. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The reality is you want a templating engine of some sort to filter your database results directly into the template.

So rather than dealing with echo commands to design a page, you want a raw template and then to inject data into that template from your database array.

You can use something standardized like [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) or roll your own fairly easily (although rudimentary):

```
$output = '';
$tpl = fopen('template.html','r');
$tpl = fread($tpl, 100000);

$templateVars = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $temporaryRow = $tpl;
    foreach ($row as $k=>$v) {
        $temporaryRow = preg_replace("/{{$k}}/i",$v,$temporaryRow);
    }
    $output .= $temporaryRow;
}

echo $output;
```

And then your template.html could be something like

```
<div>Hello, {{username}}</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what is happening in the suggested?

Comment: Sure.  As mentioned it's very rudimentary, but you're opening a template file 'template.html' that represents an injectable template.  Then as you iterate through your rows, you're adding that template to the output after replacing all instances of {{variable}} with its corresponding $row[variable] value.